# How to set a variable that is defined by the user's input? (Google Places API)

Tags: python, api, google-places-api

*I have to define a variable with the restaurant I would like to query, rather than leaving the variable undefined and passing whatever restaurant I'd like into the program.*

I have written a basic python program to query the Google places api. It takes an argument (input_1), which is where I want the user to input the restaurant they want to get the details of, and outputs predefined fields.

I want the user to be able to input whatever restaurant they want (or a string of restaurants..although that would be a bonus) and get an output. However, in it's current state I have to set input_1 equal to the restaurant. Is there a way to set input_1 to an empty string that can then be defined by the user's input? (apologies if I didn't quite explain it well enough. Also, will take any advice in regards to better ways to write the short program)

```
import requests
import urllib.parse

main_api = 
'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?'

api_key = '&key=' + ##api key
fields = 'fields=formatted_address,name,opening_hours,rating'


input_1 = ##restaurant
url = main_api + urllib.parse.urlencode({'input': input_1}) + 
'&inputtype=textquery&' + fields + api_key


def restaurant_search(input_1):
    input("Enter restaurant: ")
    apikey = api_key
    url1 = url
    json_data = requests.get(url1).json()
    # loop through object and print out key:value pairs
    for i in json_data['candidates']:
        print (i['formatted_address'])
        print (i['name'])
        print (i['opening_hours'])
        print (i['rating'])
        break

restaurant_search(input_1)
```

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure this code would work. You're collecting input, but you're not assigning it to the `input_1` variable. You can do that with `input_1 = input("Enter...")`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take input from the users, `restaurant_search` shouldn't have input as a parameter. You need to create the input_1 variable within the method.

```
def restaurant_search():
    input_1 = input("Enter restaurant: ")
    ...
```